# onresize event in CodeMirror textarea

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to call a function when user resize the CodeMirror text area. But I can't found a resize event in the event list of CodeMirror [documentation](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html). Are there any method do this. I want to do like below.

```
editor.on('resize', function(){
   consolo.log('editor resized');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `refresh` event for it:

```
editor.on("refresh", function () {
  console.log('editor resized');
});
```

According to CodeMirror's Doc: it fires when the editor is refreshed or resized.

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror does not have a built-in  event which fires when users change the editor's size. However, you can use `"refresh" (instance: CodeMirror)`. It fires when changing the size of the editor programmatically using setSize.

#### **"refresh" (instance: CodeMirror)**

> Fires when the editor is [refreshed](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#refresh) or [resized](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setSize). Mostly useful to invalidate cached values that depend on the editor or character size.

---

It is easy you can observe size of any DOM element using `ResizeObserver`.

#### ResizeObserver

> The ResizeObserver interface reports changes to the dimensions of an
> Element's content or border box, or the bounding box of an SVGElement. - [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

```
  // create an Observer instance
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    const height = entries[0].target.clientHeight;
    console.log("div.CodeMirror.CodeMirror-wrap height changed:", height);
  });
  const codeMirror = document.querySelector("div.CodeMirror.CodeMirror-wrap");
  resizeObserver.observe(codeMirror);
```

In the above code, I observe the size of the outer most element of CodeMirror. You can narrow down.